# grails - get current user globally

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, spring-security

I'm new in using Spring Security plug-in for my grails app. Here's my code in getting the current user logged in.

```
String username = getPrincipal().username
```

But the thing is I'm writing this line in every action to get the current user. Is there a way to globally get the current user? And use it in every action without declaring it again and again?

Comment: Create a class named BaseController and make every controller extend it then make a protected method in it, accessible from all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways:
1) You can inject SpringSecurityService anywhere you want, simply in any controller/service:

```
SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

def someMethod(){
   springSecurityService.principal
}
```

2) You can use SecurityContextHolder:

```
def someMethod(){
   SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication?.principal
}
```

I suggest using option 1, it makes testing easier etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get user object I suggest you to retrieve "fresh" (taken from the DB) user instance each time using the injected before `springSecurityService`:

```
springSecurityService.principal.username
```

But if you need only a username - you could create a session-scoped bean and populate it with username at the creation time:

**resources.groovy**:

```
...
userNameHolder(UserNameHolder) { bean ->
    bean.scope = 'session'
    springSecurityService = ref("springSecurityService")
}
...
```

And:

```
class UserNameHolder {
    def springSecurityService

    String username = springSecurityService.principal.username

    String getUsername() {
        username
    }
}
```

Then you should inject `UserNameHolder` to the places needed and retrieve username:

```
class SomeService {

    def userNameHolder

    void someMethod() {
        ...
        userNameHolder.username
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Enjoy!

**UPD**:

You could do almost the same by putting username into the HTTPSession, but it would be much less controlable and testable. So I strongly recommend you to use a session-scoped bean.

Comment: `springSecurityService.currentUser?.userName` Unless the `userName` property is not available on the principal, this does an unnecessary database call. `springSecurityService.principal.username` would be better.